# How do I find unfinalized files in the App Engine files API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The App Engine files API allows a file to be created either in blobstore or in cloud storage. A file basically has two states: a unfinalized state where you can still append to the file and a finalized state where the file cannot be appended but where you can read from the file or serve it through blobstore or cloud storage.

For my application I need to have a file in the unfinalized state for some time before I eventually finalize it. The docs suggest this is fine. I'm using the Java SDK.

My question is how do I find (orphaned) files that are not finalized yet? In blobstore I assume there isn't a key for it yet so I can't find it. I'm not sure how it would work with cloud storage. Are orphaned files eventually garbage collected and if so, after what time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. The files API is not very well documented, but you can look in the code of file.py. There you find a stat function.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/file.py
After I gave my answer I save that your question was about Java.

Comment: The javadocs say that stat only works on a finalized file (it's also in the pydoc), so that won't work unfortunately.